# Writing action theories in OWL + SWRL: possible?

Tags: owl, planning, swrl

In order to solve symbolic planning problems we write *action theories*.
Popular languages for writing action theories are STRIPS and ADL.

For describing an action we need to provide:

- preconditions
- effects

For example, in a robot domain, we have `Robot` and `Object` classes, and the `closeTo` and `holding` properties.

The action `pickUp(?robot, ?object)` is possible if `closeTo(?robot, ?object)` holds, and also `forall ?o in Object . not holding(?robot, ?o)`.

How would one represent preconditions with OWL and/or SWRL?

How about action effects?

Answer (score 1):

The Knowrob project suggests that it is possible to use the Qualitative Process Theory (QPT) in combination with OWL-Markup language for implementing actions. A possible precondition would be [[1]](https://github.com/knowrob/knowrob/blob/master/knowrob_actions/prolog/process_effects.pl) :

```
rdf_triple(knowrob:'thermicallyConnectedTo', Dough, HeatSource),
```

But it was never demonstrated, that this prolog-spaghetti-code will work. OWL is not a real programming language, it's more like a markup language like json. To formalize processes in a deklarative form is a academic quiz but has no relevance for gamecoding or real robotprogramming.